# MDX Query - Select Columns From Same Dimensions

Tags: mdx

I have a requirement displaying data from *same dimension* in more than 1 column. For eg. I want to show data Year and Month wise. In my dimension structure, Year and Month belongs to same hierarchy. When I run below query I get error. PFB the query.

```
Select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Target Actual Value]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY {[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Year Name].Members *
[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Month Year]} ON 1
From [Cube_BCG_OLAP]
```

The error I get is Query (2, 12) The Hierarchy hierarchy is used more than   once in the Crossjoin function. I am new to MDX queries. Please help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did mine or Sourav's answer help? or did you find an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Target Actual Value]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY {[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Year Name].Members , 
[Realization Date].[Hierarchy].[Month Year]} ON 1
From [Cube_BCG_OLAP]
```

Instead of `CROSSJOIN` have a set as above. In a set, you can put members from same hierarchy

Comment: ...glad you're back - it has been boring on here without you!

Comment: M flattered! Feels great to be missed :)

Answer (score 0):

I like Sourav's answer - but it will put the results in one column which is slightly different than the question.

In `AdvWorks` this is in one column:

```
SELECT 
  [State-Province].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It is possible to switch to two columns and use a cross join but you need to find out the details of your Date dimensions `Attribute` hierarchies (as opposed to `User` hierarchies):

```
SELECT 
  [State-Province].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS
 ,
  [Calendar Year].[All Periods].Children 
* [Month].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

In your cube maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Target Actual Value]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Year Name].MEMBERS 
  * 
    [Month Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Cube_BCG_OLAP];
```

Comment: In all practical situations, I never quite came across a situation where having the result in multiple or single column/rows mattered that much(we use ssrs). Also, this increases query's execution time which might not be a good thing. What do you say?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti true - although I have rarely wanted multiple columns in the past, and using the attribute hierarchies has been the way I've solved it. It's just an alternative approach. Sometime I quite like using attribute hierarchies if family relationships within dimensions are not important to the particular question I'm answering.